# Meaning of "condition-ut-extremis" in Dune

Tags: meaning, definitions

Excerpt From: Frank Herbert, *Dune*

“The wisdom of seeding the known universe with a prophecy pattern for the protection of B.G. personnel has long been appreciated, but never have we seen a condition-ut-extremis with more ideal mating of person and preparation.”

I think it's referring to Lady Jessica having Paul with Duke Leto—Paul to become some sort of "chosen one."

I derived a meaning from a few sources, and I am wondering if others would agree with it.

Derivation

- (dictionary) in extremis: in an extremely difficult situation; at the point of death
- (dictionary) subjunctive: relating to or denoting a mood of verbs expressing what is imagined or wished possible (compare to "indicative": denoting a mood of verbs expressing a simple statement of fact)
- ([another post](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/151/why-does-ut-mean-such-different-things-when-it-has-a-subjunctive-verb-vs-an-i?newreg=1f8e73ebd3da4ebd80bec54ea87d89b0)) ut: subjunctive: "in order to" (purpose), "to" (indirect command), or  "that" (result/fear); indicative: "(just) as"

*condition-ut-extremis*: condition created in order to survive a deadly situation

Comment: As there is no subjunctive, I think it must be *"ut"* = as. As for *"conditio"* it has three entries in L&S. *condĭtĭo,* for condĭcĭo =stipulation, condition  [http://perseus.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.2:4098.lewisandshort] ; *condĭtĭo* a creating, a work; ( *condītĭo* preserve, pickle, )

Comment: Oh hmm. Maybe the "condition" part is just English; I originally assumed it was Latin since the second and third parts looked Latin. I guess condition in the sense of "conditio"/"creation" or "work" makes the most sense, as in maybe Paul being a sort of polarizing creation.

Comment: Like a person / creation / situation as extreme.

Comment: I'm not sure we are justified in assuming that Frank Herbert got all his Latin correct and according to classical precedent.